# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.object')

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-proptypes, prop

Just created a new project using reac-native-init .
Using

```
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.51.0",
```

Running the project from xcode i am getting the below errors

> Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
>
> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.PropTypes.object')

Searched in my project directory for **_react.PropTypes.object**. It was being used only in the mobx-react folder. Now my project doesn't run, its stuck at the splash screen.
Any help is greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Now i am getting this error

> _react3.default.PropTypes.shape

But i cant find this line in my whole project

Comment: Can you share the whole error log?

Answer (score 7):

Simply import prop-types to your project.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
```

If you didn't have it in your project than first install it using yarn or npm

```
npm install prop-types
```

or

```
yarn add prop-types
```

Comment: I installed it, but its never used in my code and getting the same error

Comment: what is the exact error? @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil

Answer (score 1):

PropTypes is not included anymore in the core of RN and you need to install it manually. Try that before: https://github.com/facebook/prop-types

Although, it is very weird that you get that issue in the initial project. I don't get surprised anymore since every RN release breaks my code in half.