# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')

Tags: react-native

ERROR  TypeError: undefined is not an object

> (evaluating '_reactNative.Text.propTypes.style')

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.
ERROR  Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication). A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is incorrect.
This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early initialization error when loading React Native.

Comment: This will answer : https://stackoverflow.com/q/61226530/6654562

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47973999/6654562